# What happens when Python's self keyword is invoked as a function like self(**inputs)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading through some code and stumbled into this line of code, see the link below.
Can someone explain what's going on here?  Does this call the constructor?  I've never seen self used in such a way before.

```
outputs = self(**model_inputs)
```

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/aa925a52fad9d6b98dac4c1b27f881bef7e88dad/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L1223

Comment: `self` is not a keyword in python. Here `self` must be some kind of callable object.

Comment: It depends. Most likely the object has a __call__() method, and that will get called.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  With your help I was able to track down a __call__() method in the Module base class.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1465970a343e61f2f2b104859ca7f5d7e03f5d02/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L567